# No Internet connection on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, dual-boot, drivers

I have my laptop set to dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows.

I recently updated my internet driver through Windows using a 3rd party application. When I logged back into Ubuntu after updating the driver, the internet no longer worked.

I couldn't find any help online.

Is there any fix for this?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you booted into Windows, updated a Windows driver, logged out of Windows then booted Ubuntu ? The Windows installation and the Ubuntu installation are totally independant of each other. Can you give further details of what you mean by "the internet no longer worked" ?

Comment: About the first part, that's a yes. To explain about about "the internet no longer worked", it shows me on the top right that I am connected to the internet. Yet when I try to do something that requires internet (e.g. Firefox) it says I'm not connected.

Comment: OK, so in a terminal can you type "ifconfig" and see if you have been given an IP address ? Second, can you ping 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: I pinged 8.8.8.8 and it worked. Then, I tried typing "ifconfig" and it _did_ give me an IP. **Edit**: After digging a bit, I tried changing my DNS addr to 8.8.8.8 and it seems to work for now. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was a lack of DNS server. I guess the router DNS has somehow failed (maybe temporarily ?)